# Output from Access data pull results in * in SAS

Tags: ms-access, sas

I'm importing a dataset from Access in to SAS and one of my columns results in a * in SAS.
The value in access is numerical, but when I import the data I only get *.

I think I need to somehow change the informat. I have tried to use INPUT, INPUTC, INPUTN but nothing works.

Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: Please provide more details about what code you ran. Or if you used some GUI import tool then also what user interface you are using to run SAS (Display Manager, SAS/Studio, Enterprise Guide) and which GUI tool you used to do the import.  Provide details about how the variable is defined in the ACCESS file.

Comment: What happens if you remove the format?

Comment: Thanks for comments. Im using SAS Enterprise guide. I import the data from Access by using PROC import in SAS (I have a ODBC connection) The variable in access is numerical (i dont know the format in access). I do not apply any formats at all, the output just gives me * from my proc import. Thank you for replying to my question

Comment: PROC IMPORT might be applying the wrong format. Can you use a libname statement to log in to the Access database with ODBC? I would be curious what the dataset looks like when accessed through a library. If you can do that, I would recommend using direct libname access for it and doing your regular data prep from there.